# .net framework split function not working properly

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have written the following function in VB.net:

```
Public Function split_ondotspaces (ByVal thetext As String) As String()
    thetext = thetext.Replace("\n", ". ")
    Dim sntncs() As String
    Dim sperator As String = ". "
    sntncs = thetext.Split(sperator)
    Return sntncs
End Function
```

but it seems to split the text on every single dot that it finds in the text not only on ". " (dot + space) locations like it is supposed to. Any ways to fix it and get it to work properly?

Comment: Sorry if this seems totally inexperienced. I am new to programming, and stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to [use](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx) `overloads on the String.Split method to do split based on multiple characters`

```
   sntncs = thetext.Split(New String() {sperator}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```